# MIPS Programming: Storing and Integer and Printing its ASCII Character

Tags: assembly, integer, character, ascii, mips

I'm new to assembly language and I'm trying to have the user enter an integer between 1 and 26 to keep it simple, and then print the ASCII character that's associated with that integer. However, when it prints out the integer it prints some odd looking symbol rather than a letter, character etc. Here's my code:

```
    .data 
prompt1:    .asciiz "Enter the value of n here: " 
prompt2:    .asciiz "The letter is: "
outside:    .asciiz "?"

.globl  main
.text
main: 
li $t1, 1   #register to check for 1
li $t2, 27  #register for no numbers over 26
li $v0, 4   #prompt user for integer
la $a0, prompt1
syscall
li $v0, 5   #store the integer the user inputed
syscall
add $t0, $0, $v0 #store that number in register
blt $t0, $t1, outOfBounds #if less than 1, print a ?
blt $t0, $t2, print #if okay, go to print the ascii character
j   outOfBounds 
print:
li $v0, 11
move $a0, $t0
syscall
j   Exit
outOfBounds:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, outside
syscall
j   Exit
Exit:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: what is -- call 11 -- on line hrmm??

Comment: syscall 11 is print_character.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
move $a0, $t0
```

With this:

```
addiu $a0, $t0, 'A'-1  # Converts the value in the range 1-26 to a character
                       # in the range 'A'-'Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

The printable ASCII characters start at 32 and ends around 126, so limiting input to this range would result in sensible output.

Comment: The OP wants to print the n:th character in the alphabet (e.g. the user inputs 3 => print the letter C).

Answer (score 0):

```
1     .data 
2   prompt1:    .asciiz "Enter the value of n here: " 
3   prompt2:    .asciiz "The letter is: "
4   outside:    .asciiz "?"
5
6   .globl  main
7   .text
8   main: 
9   li $t1, 1               # register to check for 1
10  li $t2, 27              # register for no numbers over 26
11  li $v0, 4               # prompt user for integer
12  la $a0, prompt1
13  syscall
14  li $v0, 5               # store the integer the user inputed
15  syscall
16  add $t0, $0, $v0                  # store that number in register
17  blt $t0, $t1, outOfBounds             # if less than 1, print a ?
18  blt $t0, $t2, print                   # if okay, go to print the ascii character
19  j   outOfBounds 
20  print:
21  li $v0, 11
22  move $a0, $t0
23  syscall
24  j   Exit
25  outOfBounds:
26  li $v0, 4
27  la $a0, outside
28  syscall
29  j   Exit
30  Exit:
31  li $v0, 10
32  syscall
```

Comment: How is this different from the code the OP posted in his question? From the looks of it you just added line numbers, or am I missing something?

Comment: the line numbers sorta help.